# Cannot find a version of 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' that satisfies the version constraints

Tags: java, android, gradle, build, apk

When generated signed APK for realse i get this error message:

```
Cannot find a version of 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' that satisfies the version constraints: 
   Dependency path 'XX:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.2-alpha01' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
   Constraint path 'XX:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' strictly '1.3.9' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9
```

This is my app:gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.XX.XX"
    minSdkVersion 25
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}


 }

 dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:22.0-android'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha01'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.2-alpha01'
}
```

However if i build for debug it works fine, but when i generate signed release I get this message, ive tried to google but didnt seem to find the right answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem today and found this :
https://github.com/trello/RxLifecycle/issues/154

Manged to fix my problem by editing  the Gradle Scripts build.gradle in the  (module:app) under dependancies adding :

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
```

I originally tried a different version number but got an error that told me what version to use, so you may need to have a couple of tries.

Comment: It is also related when using `stetho`, `espresso-core` both dependency using `findbugs:2.0.1`, conflicted when we also use `truth` that already moved to `findbugs:3.0.2` as stated [here + solutions](https://github.com/google/truth/issues/525#issuecomment-571697739). ignore the `findbugs` with your needed version

Comment: for the future reader, you might wanna check for my other answer here regarding steps to resolve any [conflicted transitive dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59808418/3763032) including `findbugs, androidx.test:monitor, guava, etc`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of exact cause of this problem. However, after trying several options, it automatically started working

If you are using Room component, and writing tests for it. You need to add the following dependencies.

```
// optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:2.1.0"

// Test helpers
testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

For those wondering how to solve the dependencies conflict issues.

**My dependencies:**

```
// Conflicted transitive dependency for androidx.test:monitor
- org.robolectric:robolectric -> androidx.test:monitor:1.2.0 (forced to use 1.1.0)
- androidx.test:core -> androidx.test:monitor:1.1.0
- androidx.test:runner -> androidx.test:monitor:1.1.0

// Conflicted transitive dependency for com.google.guava:listenablefuture
- androidx.test.ext:truth -> androidx.test:monitor:9999.0 (forced to use 1.0)
- androidx.work:work-runtime -> androidx.test:monitor:1.0
```

**Resolutions 1**

I ended-up checking for the `Required by` & `Could not resolve [dependency]` **keyword** to ***determine*** and ***choose*** which version I want to ***include***, e.g: `androidx.test:monitor:1.1.0` & `com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0` and then ***exclude*** for the rest by doing something like this:

```
    androidTestImplementation(org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3.1) {
        exclude(group = "androidx.test", module = "monitor")
        exclude(group = "com.google.guava", module = "listenablefuture")
    }
```

I'm forcing the exclude `androidx.test:module` from `org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3.1` and to use the `androidx.test:module:1.1.0` that required by both `androidx.test:core` & `androix.test:runner`.

Also the same for `guavalistener` I'm not using truth, so I remove it, but if you do need it, you can do the same to exclude/choose the ***required dependency*** that you want to include

**Resolutions 2**

If you using roboelectric, you might wanna to exclude a few dependencies as well like here from @finder2 [java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class org.apache.maven.artifact.Artifact found in modules maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57819278/3763032)

The above method was a hotfix, also you might want to choose carefully which transitive dependency that you want to use or just remove the dependency that you don't needed (`truth` is for my example)

Below is the error build output after fixing the `findbugs` dependencies conflict, and with the above method, I'm able to fix it.

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDevDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:devDebugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve androidx.test:monitor:{strictly 1.1.0}.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.test:monitor' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'android-etalase-app:app:unspecified' --> 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3.1' --> 'androidx.test:monitor:1.2.0'
           Constraint path 'android-etalase-app:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test:monitor:{strictly 1.1.0}' because of the following reason: devDebugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.1.0
           Dependency path 'android-etalase-app:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test:core:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.test:monitor:1.1.0'
           Dependency path 'android-etalase-app:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0' --> 'androidx.test:monitor:1.1.0'
           Dependency path 'android-etalase-app:app:unspecified' --> 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3.1' --> 'org.robolectric:shadows-framework:4.3.1' --> 'androidx.test:monitor:1.2.0'

   > Could not resolve androidx.test:monitor:1.2.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3.1
         project :app > org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3.1 > org.robolectric:shadows-framework:4.3.1
      > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.test:monitor' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'android-etalase-app:app:unspecified' --> 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3.1' --> 'androidx.test:monitor:1.2.0'
           Constraint path 'android-etalase-app:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test:monitor:{strictly 1.1.0}' because of the following reason: devDebugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.1.0
           Dependency path 'android-etalase-app:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test:core:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.test:monitor:1.1.0'
           Dependency path 'android-etalase-app:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0' --> 'androidx.test:monitor:1.1.0'
           Dependency path 'android-etalase-app:app:unspecified' --> 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3.1' --> 'org.robolectric:shadows-framework:4.3.1' --> 'androidx.test:monitor:1.2.0'

   > Could not resolve androidx.test:monitor:1.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > androidx.test:core:1.0.0
         project :app > androidx.test:runner:1.1.0
      > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.test:monitor' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'android-etalase-app:app:unspecified' --> 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3.1' --> 'androidx.test:monitor:1.2.0'
           Constraint path 'android-etalase-app:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test:monitor:{strictly 1.1.0}' because of the following reason: devDebugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.1.0
           Dependency path 'android-etalase-app:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test:core:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.test:monitor:1.1.0'
           Dependency path 'android-etalase-app:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0' --> 'androidx.test:monitor:1.1.0'
           Dependency path 'android-etalase-app:app:unspecified' --> 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3.1' --> 'org.robolectric:shadows-framework:4.3.1' --> 'androidx.test:monitor:1.2.0'

   > Could not resolve com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > androidx.work:work-runtime:2.2.0
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'android-etalase-app:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.2.0' --> 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0'
           Constraint path 'android-etalase-app:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:{strictly 1.0}' because of the following reason: devDebugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0
           Dependency path 'android-etalase-app:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.0.0' --> 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre' --> 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'

   > Could not resolve com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.
     Required by:
         project :app > androidx.test.ext:truth:1.0.0 > com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'android-etalase-app:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.2.0' --> 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0'
           Constraint path 'android-etalase-app:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:{strictly 1.0}' because of the following reason: devDebugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0
           Dependency path 'android-etalase-app:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.0.0' --> 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre' --> 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'
```

Comment: "Resolutions 1" option worked in my case, thanks. ( exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'jsr305' )

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me thanks to StackOverflow

past inside **app.gradle** file

```
 android 
 {
    configurations.all 
    {
      resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try.
Method 1:
comment out or delete in the app: gradle lines related to the tests 'androidTestImplementation';
Method 2:
In the "open / edit run" window of Android Studio, the option "app" should be selected.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esCPJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
android 
 {
    configurations.all 
    {
      resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
 }
```