# How to resolve duplicated gradle Dependency issues

Tags: gradle, robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I have tried to test my code with robolectric. Problem is that it has duplicated References. e.g.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class org.apache.maven.artifact.Artifact found in modules maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar (org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.3) and maven-artifact-2.2.1.jar (org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:2.2.1)
```

I have used the gradel artifact `app:dependencies` to get the following report. Here the important parts:

```
+--- org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3
|    +--- org.robolectric:annotations:4.3
|    +--- org.robolectric:junit:4.3
|    |    +--- org.robolectric:annotations:4.3
|    |    +--- org.robolectric:sandbox:4.3
|    |    |    +--- org.robolectric:annotations:4.3
|    |    |    +--- org.robolectric:utils:4.3
|    |    |    |    +--- org.robolectric:annotations:4.3
|    |    |    |    +--- org.robolectric:pluginapi:4.3
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.robolectric:annotations:4.3
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.8.0
|    |    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.3
|    |    |    |    |         +--- org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |         +--- classworlds:classworlds:1.1-alpha-2
|    |    |    |    |         +--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1
|    |    |    |    |         |    +--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:1.0.4 -> 1.5.15
|    |    |    |    |         |    \--- classworlds:classworlds:1.1-alpha-2
|    |    |    |    |         +--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:1.5.15
|    |    |    |    |         +--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:1.11
|    |    |    |    |         +--- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:2.2.1
|    |    |    |    |         |    \--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:1.5.15
|    |    |    |    |         +--- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:2.2.1
|    |    |    |    |         |    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:2.2.1
|    |    |    |    |         |    |    \--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:1.5.15
|    |    |    |    |         |    +--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:1.5.15
|    |    |    |    |         |    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:2.2.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |         |    +--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |         |    +--- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:1.0-beta-6
|    |    |    |    |         |    |    \--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:1.4.2 -> 1.5.15
|    |    |    |    |         |    \--- backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:3.1
|    |    |    |    |         +--- org.apache.maven:maven-model:2.2.1
|    |    |    |    |         |    \--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:1.5.15
|    |    |    |    |         +--- org.apache.maven:maven-project:2.2.1
|    |    |    |    |         |    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:2.2.1
|    |    |    |    |         |    |    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-model:2.2.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |         |    |    +--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:1.11
|    |    |    |    |         |    |    +--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:1.5.15
|    |    |    |    |         |    |    \--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |         |    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-profile:2.2.1
|    |    |    |    |         |    |    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-model:2.2.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |         |    |    +--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:1.5.15
|    |    |    |    |         |    |    +--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:1.11
|    |    |    |    |         |    |    \--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |         |    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-model:2.2.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |         |    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:2.2.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |         |    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:2.2.1
|    |    |    |    |         |    |    +--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:1.5.15
|    |    |    |    |         |    |    \--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |         |    +--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:1.11
|    |    |    |    |         |    +--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:1.5.15
|    |    |    |    |         |    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:2.2.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |         |    \--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |         +--- org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:2.2.1
|    |    |    |    |         |    \--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |         +--- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:2.2.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |         +--- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-file:1.0-beta-6
|    |    |    |    |         |    \--- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:1.0-beta-6 (*)
|    |    |    |    |         +--- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-lightweight:1.0-beta-6
|    |    |    |    |         |    +--- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-shared:1.0-beta-6
|    |    |    |    |         |    |    +--- nekohtml:xercesMinimal:1.9.6.2
|    |    |    |    |         |    |    +--- nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.6.2
|    |    |    |    |         |    |    \--- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:1.0-beta-6 (*)
|    |    |    |    |         |    \--- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:1.0-beta-6 (*)
|    |    |    |    |         \--- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:1.0-beta-6 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- org.robolectric:utils-reflector:4.3
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:7.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:7.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:7.0
|    |    |    |    |    |         \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:7.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:7.0
|    |    |    |    |         +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0
|    |    |    |    |         +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:7.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |         \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:7.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc4
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.auto:auto-common:0.8
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 27.0.1-jre
|    |    |    |    |    |         +--- com.google.guava:failureaccess:1.0.1
|    |    |    |    |    |         +--- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava
|    |    |    |    |    |         +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2
|    |    |    |    |    |         +--- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.5.2
|    |    |    |    |    |         +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.2.0
|    |    |    |    |    |         +--- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.1
|    |    |    |    |    |         \--- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:1.17
|    |    |    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:23.5-jre -> 27.0.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    |    |    |    \--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2
|    |    |    +--- org.robolectric:shadowapi:4.3
|    |    |    |    \--- org.robolectric:annotations:4.3
|    |    |    +--- org.robolectric:utils-reflector:4.3 (*)
|    |    |    +--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2
|    |    |    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    |    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0
|    |    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:7.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- org.robolectric:pluginapi:4.3 (*)
|    |    +--- org.robolectric:shadowapi:4.3 (*)
|    |    \--- org.robolectric:utils-reflector:4.3 (*)
|    +--- org.robolectric:pluginapi:4.3 (*)
|    +--- org.robolectric:resources:4.3
|    |    +--- org.robolectric:utils:4.3 (*)
|    |    +--- org.robolectric:annotations:4.3
|    |    +--- org.robolectric:pluginapi:4.3 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre (*)
|    +--- org.robolectric:sandbox:4.3 (*)
|    +--- org.robolectric:utils:4.3 (*)
|    +--- org.robolectric:utils-reflector:4.3 (*)
|    +--- org.robolectric:plugins-maven-dependency-resolver:4.3
|    |    +--- org.robolectric:pluginapi:4.3 (*)
|    |    +--- org.robolectric:utils:4.3 (*)
|    |    +--- org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.0 (*)
|    |    \--- org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.3 (*)
|    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    +--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2
|    +--- org.robolectric:shadows-framework:4.3
|    |    +--- org.robolectric:annotations:4.3
|    |    +--- org.robolectric:resources:4.3 (*)
|    |    +--- org.robolectric:pluginapi:4.3 (*)
|    |    +--- org.robolectric:shadowapi:4.3 (*)
|    |    +--- org.robolectric:utils:4.3 (*)
|    |    +--- org.robolectric:utils-reflector:4.3 (*)
|    |    +--- androidx.test:monitor:1.2.0 -> 1.3.0-alpha02 (*)
|    |    +--- com.almworks.sqlite4java:sqlite4java:0.282
|    |    +--- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:53.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.apps.common.testing.accessibility.framework:accessibility-test-framework:2.1
|    |    |    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    |    |    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.6.1
|    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0
|    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.52
|    \--- androidx.test:monitor:1.2.0 -> 1.3.0-alpha02 (*)
```

How to resolve the reference error? It seems to me that robolectric has the same class in diffrent dependencies?

I use the following build script:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    useLibrary 'android.test.runner'

    useLibrary 'android.test.base'
    useLibrary 'android.test.mock'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sampleapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.1-alpha02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3'

    // Mail-Versand
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.2'
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.2'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'//
    implementation 'com.github.woxthebox:draglistview:1.6.6'
}
```

How to fix that?

Issue on github is open: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/5235

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Finally get the test running. I've excluded all libs with duplicated classes:

```
testImplementation ("org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3"){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.maven', module: 'maven-artifact'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.maven', module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.maven', module: 'maven-model'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.maven', module: 'maven-plugin-registry'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.maven', module: 'maven-profile'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.maven', module: 'maven-project'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.maven', module: 'maven-settings'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.maven', module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
    exclude group: "org.apache.maven.wagon"
}
```

Not all possibilities tested but a simple test worked already.

Comment: you are a lifesaver @finder2

Comment: Just in case: I have to add this exclude for protobuf also
`exclude group: "com.google.protobuf", module: "protobuf-java"`

Answer (score 7):

This probably could be written in more general way:

```
testImplementation ("org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3") {
    exclude group "org.apache.maven.wagon"
    exclude group "org.apache.maven"
}
```

or even:

```
testImplementation ("org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3") {
    exclude group: "org.apache.maven", name: "maven-ant-tasks"
}
```

because it is [maven-ant-tasks](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven/maven-ant-tasks/2.1.3) of [pluginapi](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.robolectric/pluginapi/4.3), which pulls in `org.apache.maven` dependencies.

Comment: This doesn't work. It seems great, but you also exclude with org.apache.maven the group maven-ant-tasks. This causes a `ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.DependenciesTask`. The idea to exclude the whole group is great. I've used it for excluding `org.apache.maven.wagon`

Comment: unfortunately, in my case, `org.codehaus.classworld` that `roboelectric 4.3.1` used duplicate as well, even though I've excluded using the group, it will show `ClassNotFound` as well @finder2

Comment: @mochadwi if you'd post a new question, providing `dependencies` and notify me with it's URL, I'd likely could solve the issue. `ClassNotFound` usually only happens, when excluding too much.

Comment: Think that one has to use `debugImplementation` for one of the packages (would need to see which one it was). These are `dependencies` for two whole different applications; at least on Android.

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered the same issue and the thing that helped me was that I had defined the Roboelectric dependency twice in Gradle file one with androidTestImplementation and the other with testImplementation so when I removed the first part problem solved!!!

Comment: you're also a lifesaver man @alireza-rahmaty. I don't know why I need to add `testImplementation` for roboelectric. That means for instrumentation, which is doesn't needed for unitTest directory.

thanks again man

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to ensure that I was not requiring Robolectric in my `androidTestImplementation` dependencies.

Once I fixed that, I did not have any conflicts to fix.