# When Generate Signed APK - Cannot find a version of 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk

When I am trying to Generate a signed APK build  its failed with the below errors.

````
   Dependency path 'MyApp:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
   Constraint path 'MyApp:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:{strictly 1.3.9}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.3.9 ```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find a version of 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' that satisfies the version constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520546/cannot-find-a-version-of-com-google-code-findbugsjsr305-that-satisfies-the-ve)

Comment: @EraftYps Thanks for replying, i tried it but it still giving me the same error